# SQL error missing right parentheses

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL and I am doing an assignment for class. I do not understand what is wrong with the statement below.

```
CREATE TABLE APP_DEGREE 
    (DEGREE_ID varchar (6) NOT NULL,
    TITLE varchar (3O), 
    INSTITUTION varchar (30), 
    App_ID varchar (6) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT constr_degree_pk PRIMARY KEY (DEGREE_ID), 
    CONSTRAINT constr_degree_fk FOREIGN KEY (App_ID) REFERENCES APPLICANT (App_ID)
    );
```

When I run the script I receive this error:

```
Error report -
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Apart from the obvious mistake you've already been pointed to, consider using VARCHAR**2** instead of VARCHAR as Oracle suggests to "always use the VARCHAR2 datatype to store variable-length character strings."

Answer (score 4):

Typo:  TITLE varchar (30) and not TITLE varchar(3O)

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE APP_DEGREE(
    DEGREE_ID varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    TITLE varchar(30), 
    INSTITUTION varchar(30), 
    App_ID varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT constr_degree_pk PRIMARY KEY(DEGREE_ID), 
    CONSTRAINT constr_degree_fk FOREIGN KEY(App_ID) REFERENCES APPLICANT(App_ID)
);
```

Edit: The "O" instead "0". Use an IDE, you will see this kind of errors instantly. Also the "`" string delimiter to have not to deal with reserved sql keywords like "order" as field name.

Comment: i think you have tried to format words visually with ``` characters, but those yield ORA-00911 invalid character error ...

Comment: This looks like mysql syntax, but this question is tagged with Oracle.

Comment: Didn't see the Oracle tag, my bad. Edited

Comment: "Use an IDE ..." - actually SQL Developer doesn't spot this, oddly.

Comment: At least SQL\*Plus puts an asterisk right under the offending character; with a little bit of luck, you may realize it's a typo. With SQL Developer, the specific info about which position (character) on which line causes the problem is not given. Definitely a bug in SQL Developer...